# Angular: Providing methods to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've taken up Angular recently as a learning exercise.

I'd like to pass a method to `ng-model` or an expression which might evaluate to one.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C4aGk/ you'll see that I've hard coded the field as `ng-model="record.inner[0].text"` and it works, now the thing is, i'd like to replace the hard-coded zero with something that is returned at run-time, selected by a criterion say `id = 1`.

My HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" ng-app>
    <div ng-repeat="record in records">
        <input ng-model="record.inner[0].text"> <span>{{record.outer}}</span>
        <div ng-repeat="nested in record.inner">{{nested.id}} - {{nested.text}}</div>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
```

and the corresponding js:

```
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.records = [{
        outer: "Hello",
        inner: [{
            id: 1,
            text: "Angular"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            text: "jQuery"
        }]
    }, {
        outer: "World",
        inner: [{
            id: 1,
            text: "Node.js"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            text: "Underscore.js"
        }]
    }];

    $scope.getText = function (record) {
        var index = 0;
        for (nested in record.inner) {
            if (nested.id === 1) {
                return "record.inner[" + index + "].text";
            }
            index++;
        }
    };
```

I've tried placing `ng-model="getText(record)"` as per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Pef6LY2rT7g with no success, and another search turned up this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1328 which is equally unhelpful to me.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a bug in your `getText` function.  `for/in` loops don't work like that in JavaScript.  You'd need to change the if statement to `if (record.inner[nested].id === 1) {`.  Either way, that won't fix your whole problem.  It might be better to describe what you're trying to do and not how you're trying to do it.  For example, if you're just trying to let the user edit [0] or [1] after clicking an Edit button, it would be better/easier, in Angular, to have separate fields that you show/hide.

Comment: Thank you @Langdon for catching the mistake, I normally avoid the `for/in` loops so I'm a bit rusty. I'm following Dan Wahlin's guide to Angular JS and I was trying to remake the customer app referenced in the presentation when it occurred to me to try this and since it should have worked as per the links I cited. I thought it must be something I'm doing wrong. I'm just exploring the directives at the moment, that's where the question came from. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything that you pass into ng-model is evaluated as an angular expression against the scope. That means that `record.inner[0].text` is evaluated as `$scope.record.inner[0].text` and then the result of that expression is used. When you use `getText(record)`, angular evaluates `$scope.getText(record)` and ng-model gets access to the result of this evaluation. Keep in mind that ng-model does not evaluate the result of this function call.

Your problem is that you are returning the result as an angular expression string, but never evaluating it, so ng-model is given a string that it cannot use. There are lots of ways to redesign your code to deal with this, but the simple (and probably not best) way would be to use something like ng-init to get the result of the function call and then insert that result into the ng-model. See this fiddle for a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/z5z9s/

Comment: I don't think `ng-model="{{scopeFunctionThatReturnsAString()}}"` is supposed to work.  Do you have an example of it?

Comment: @Langdon You are correct. Thanks for catching that! I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I might just go with this if nothing better is available. If you don't mind explaining, the Angular documentation says `ngModel – {string} – Assignable angular expression to data-bind to.`, what does this imply if not what I did? I haven't been able to get any functions to work in the `ng-model` directive at all.

Comment: `ng-model` is looking for an actual angular expression to use for two-way data-binding. The function that you gave it returned a valid expression, but `ng-model` is unable to call a function to get an expression. It just needs the expression.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanation.